# C# - Automatically switch between two different IME in the same keyboard layout

Tags: c#, localization, cjk, ime

I did an application to enter chinese pinyin and hanzi in a database.
That means that the operator have to switch constantly between "Pinyinput" and "sogou input" with ctrl+shift
There is a way to make the IME change automaticall when a textbox is selected?
I mean, not switch the keyboard layout, just the input method of the same keyboard layout

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this, I'm not sure about the name of the languages, try to debug it and get the right name if it didn't work.

```
public void ToPinyinput()
        {
                string CName= "";
                foreach(InputLanguage lang in InputLanguage.InstalledInputLanguages) 
                {
                        CName = lang.Culture.EnglishName.ToString();

                        if(CName.StartsWith("Pinyinput"))
                        {
                                InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage = lang;
                        }
                }

        }


public void Tosogou()
        {
                string CName= "";
                foreach(InputLanguage lang in InputLanguage.InstalledInputLanguages) 
                {
                        CName = lang.Culture.EnglishName.ToString();

                        if(CName.StartsWith("sogou"))
                        {
                                InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage = lang;
                        }
                }

        }
```

if it didn't work, you need to change the following line to the correct lang name:

```
CName.StartsWith("langName")
```

Comment: this code is working, thank you! But it can only switch between languages, not between input methods in the same language (culture)

Comment: change CName = lang.Culture.EnglishName.ToString(); with CName = lang.LayoutName.ToString(); and the code is perfect! Thank you!!!!